# print() in IE doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs4

I attemt to create a print about serveral hours. Me and my colleague means, that it  should works. But it doesn't work.

If I starte the Page, the Ext.window() opens. Than I click on my 'print' button it works perfect - in Google Chrom... 
But ... 
IE means **NO** with that message :

> " SCRIPT5007: Die Eigenschaft "innerHTML" eines undefinierten oder
>   Nullverweises kann nicht festgelegt werden. "

But if I show to the `console.info();` output I see that both `contentWindow` and `panInv` contains the the `innerHTML` object on the correct position

That is the result in **IE11** simulation **IE8**.

If I stop the IE8 simulation there is no error and no warning, but - the dialog-box doesn't appear. But if i hit F5 to refresh the page, on the refreshed page the print-dialog-box appears.

Who can give me a hint. I know, there are alot of threads about this topic, and I read a lot and I try the moste of them --> without a success. awful afternoon.

Here is the handler code:

```
handler: function () {
    var panInv = Ext.getCmp('panel_inventurliste'), pFrame = Ext.get('printerFrame');
    if (!pFrame) {
        Ext.getBody().insertHtml("beforeEnd", "<iframe id='printerFrame' style='display:none'> </iframe>");
        pFrame = Ext.get('printerFrame');
    }
    var contentWindow = pFrame.dom.contentWindow;

  console.info(window);

    contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = panInv.body.dom.innerHTML;
    contentWindow.document.close();
    contentWindow.focus();
    contentWindow.print();  
}
```

Comment: From the error, it sounds like contentWindow.document.body is null.   OR ..... panInv.body.dom is null .......... I would check those values before you set the value on that line to see what the values are in Chrome, and then see what they are in IE8 simulation.

Comment: @MacGyver : Thanke you for your response and hint. But I done an other way. Now I open a new tab in the browser, so the user can open the list and keep on working at the application. Now I go this way           <pre>   var msg = panInv.body.dom.innerHTML;
                        var newwindow = window.open();
                        var newdocument = newwindow.document;
                        newdocument.write(msg);
                        newdocument.close(); </pre>

Comment: That's good news.  One thing I wanted to mention is that most Javascript frameworks have functions dedicated to fix cross browser compatibility issues (especially for IE).  It looks like you are using Javascript DOM objects to get access to the element in the HTML page.  I often search for the same command(s) in the framework source code to see if there is a wrapping function that handles the different browsers appropriately.